# Is there a way to mathematically generate a given index of a sorted permutation sum array given the source set in O(1) or O(log N) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, partitioning

I'm given a set of integers of size N in sorted, ascending order. For simplicity, this array "arr" is as follows: `[a0, a1, a2, ..., aN]`. I need the array of the sum of all pairs `ai` and `aj`, with duplicates allowed: `[a0 + a0, a0 + a1, a0 + a2, ..., a1 + a0, a1 + a1, ... aN + aN]`, size N^2. However, I need it in sorted order to binary search across it (in O(log(N^2)) time) without having to generate the entire array, which would take O(N^2 log(N^2)) time. As a binary search only needs the values of the array at certain indices, I was wondering if there was a mathematical function to determine the value of the sorted permutation sum array given a specific index (e.g. `value(3)` would return `ak + am`), allowing me to binary search across the array without generating it in full? I was thinking something like:

```
int value(int index) {
     return arr[index/N] + arr[index%N];
}
```

but this doesn't take into account that the value of `arr[i] + arr[k]` may be greater than `arr[i+1] + arr[k-5]`, for instance, even though `arr[i+1] > arr[i]`. TLDR; is there any way I could partition in less than O(N) time for this special case of array? For my own purposes, I could also accept a solution that generates the entire sorted array in less than O(N^2) time.

Comment: In the worst case any pair could be the k-th element (save for a few trivial cases with k=1,2,n^2-1 and n^2) so at a minimum you'd have to go through all pairs once to keep track of the k smallest pairs which is an n^2 time. The fact your original array is sorted doesn't actually help at all. If for example a0=1 and a1=100 then anything between 101 and 200 could be the 3rd element which could happen in a large number of ways. You will still need to exhaustively check large combinations of elements to be sure you haven't missed one

Comment: @apokryfos Are you saying we can't do better than O(n^2) for finding the kth-smallest of the n^2 sums?

Comment: @user2533504 What's the result of your binary search and what are you doing with it?

Comment: Do you know your binary search queries in advance? If you have a batch of queries to process, you may get a speedup on the whole algorithm by processing the queries in sorted order.

Comment: @KellyBundy I basically just want a way to quickly find how many elements in the n^2 array are less than a certain number k, a.k.a. k's index in the sorted array.

Comment: @kcsquared I'm actually looping over all k's from 0 to a certain constant. This leads me to think that the problem I'm doing probably involves some memoization or dp, as the bounds are so large that there is no way I would be able to do an operation of O(N) for each k.

Comment: Seems like @kcsquared is right then, you're asking for help with a bad approach instead of asking for a good approach. While the question as stated is somewhat interesting on its own, I still find that wasteful. See https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to generate the entire 2D array in time less than `O(N^2)`, because you need to do `O(1)` work to append/insert each value into your array, and there's `N^2` elements to do this for. This automatically entails `O(N^2)` work.

However, you may be able to query without constructing the full array. I highly suspect that you won't be able to beat `O(n)` time. The reason I say that is because the only reason we can query a sorted list in `O(log n)` time is because we've put in prior work to sort those elements, which required inspecting each element and doing some work (thus, at least `O(n)`), and my gut tells me we're in a similar scenario here, only we haven't yet done the necessary precomputation.

Now, you can query it in `O(n)` time as is. Start by initializing two pointers- `base` and `count`, where `base` points to the first element in the list, and `count` points to the last element. Also initialize an integer `total` to `0`. For each step, do the following:

- move `count` backwards (towards the first element) until the value `count` points to plus the value `base` points to sum to less than the query value (`*count + *base < query`).
- add the `count` (the index / offset) to `total`
- move `base` forwards
- repeat until just after either pointer hits its far end (inclusive)

The `base` pointer represents a value that we wish to know how many other elements could be added to and still be less than the query value. The pointer `count` indicates the last element that can can be added to `base` and still be less than the query value, so adding `count` (the index) for each `base` gives us the total number of pairs of elements that would sum less than the query. All together, this is `O(n)` since we just iterate over the initial array, once in each direction, at most.

Comment: This solves OP's actual problem of performing a binary search given a query *value*. Do you know if the same two pointer method could be extended to the question in the title, of finding a value given a query *index*?

Comment: @kcsquared Saddleback search does play a role in [this algorithm](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~andy/pubs/X+Y.pdf) for a more general problem.